# custom Web Template for Team site not showing Promoted links

Tags: 2013, web-template, team-sites, onet

I have created a custom web template which uses onet.xml file of 15hive\TEMPLATE\SiteTemplates\sts\xml and following is the element.xml file. However when I create a sub site based on this custom team site it is empty and does not contain promoted liks. I would like to add Promoted links to the custom web template. Here is the element.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <WebTemplate
     Name="MyTeamSite"
     BaseTemplateName="STS"
     BaseTemplateID="1"
     BaseConfigurationID="0"
     Title="Samarbetsportalen"
     Description="blahblah)."
     DisplayCategory="mygroup"/>
</Elements>
```

I tried to add the web part to the onet.xml like this but it still empty

```
  <AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="Left" WebPartOrder="0">
           <![CDATA[
                 <WebPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
                     <Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
                     <TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.GettingStartedWebPart</TypeName>
                     <Title>title</Title>
                     <Description>description</Description>
                 </WebPart>
                    ]]>
    </AllUsersWebPart>
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot provision Web Parts in Modules element using a Web Template. Consider adding a feature receiver or a Module SPI.

Comment: Thanks, Actually it is provisioned but it provisioned to default.aspx not sitepages/home.aspx. Yes using features but not so easy to add webparts to wiki pages.